# When SelectableChannel register method will get CancelledKeyException

Tags: java, netty, nio

JDK `SelectableChannel`'s `SelectionKey register(Selector sel, int ops, Object att)` will throw `CancelledKeyException`.  I want to know which scenario this method will throw this exception.

Java Doc has a simple explain:

> If this channel is currently registered with the given selector but the corresponding key has already been cancelled

But what is the corresponding key? Since this key will return after this method invoked success.  So I am confused.  Does another thread registers the same channel on the same selector will get the corresponding key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the channel is already registered with this selector, the corresponding key is modified according to the new parameters and returned, instead of a new key being constructed. If it is a cancelled key, the exception will be thrown.